# SQL Server Compact 4.0 and Sync Framework 2.1: Why the lack of support?

Tags: sql-server-ce, microsoft-sync-framework

I've spent a year developing a business desktop application for a client, and just recently upgraded its local database to SQL Compact Edition 4.0. Now I'm looking at ways to "replicate"  the data to Azure so that outside parties can use an app to access that replicated site data, run reports, etc. From the reading I've done, it appears that SQL CE 4.0 does not support this scenario, and that Microsoft recommends that if developers want to do these sorts of things, that they stick with old v3.5. I get an uneasy feeling about all this. First of all, I can't use v3.5 with Entity Framework 5.0, which Microsoft does recommend. But in general, does this lack of support indicate that the Sync Framework is not the favored solution for my type of problem? I'm a bit of a novice, but I assume that occasionally connected apps, and/or apps that allow users to work with the same data on their phone as on their desktop, is a common programming problem--one that would warrant a standard, up-to-date, supported set of technologies. So... what am I missing? Is Sync Framework somehow obsolete or unfavored? Or is the same true for SQL CE as used for desktop applications?

Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily make Sync Farmewrork Work with SQLCE 4.0, see JuneT blog. Further developement of SQLCE is not currently planned, but 4.0 is fully supported by MS in the forseeable future. My SQL CE toolbox can help you get started with Sync Framework, has some codegen features.

Comment: Hi Erik. I actually had read that post you referred to. The article states "Again, just to remind you, as per Microsoft documentation, this is not supported. ... So no blaming if it breaks or corrupts your databases." This, in combination with the trouble that some users commented about, gives off the impression that this solution is in the realm of a "hack". The thought of developing a business-critical application that depends this kind of a workaround is disturbing, because it feels like I'm venturing into a realm that wasn't meant to exist.